# Save custom value in sales_shipment_item

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping

i have custom attribute ("current_seller_id") in `sales_shipment_item` table and want to save custom value in it when click on submit invoice

Can any one tell me which `event` or use `plugin` method for saving value when data save in `sales_shipment_item` table.

And also find to know same value save in `sales_shipment` table. `current_seller_id` attribute also in `sales_shipment` table.

Please guide me little bit which `event` use or `plugin` ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I find event event `sales_order_shipment_save_before` and save value in `sales_shipment_items`  and now want to value also save in `sales_shipment` table

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: @magefms see aner Dear . i post code

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/fahu/6a06e018803ec9c4b99ada2be5ae6dc1

Answer (score 0):

`VendorName/ModuleName/etc/event.xml`
Past this code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
        <observer name="set_attribute_in_order" instance="VendorName/ModuleName\Observer\Shipment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

make class that define in instance in `VendorName/ModuleName\Observer\Shipment`

and Past this code 
my custom attribute is `current_seller_id`

```
<?php
namespace Codility\VendorOrder\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Shipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $authSession;
    public function __construct( \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
                                 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $this->authSession=$authSession;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $current_user_id=$this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId();
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        foreach ($shipment->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            $item->setCurrentSellerId($current_user_id);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This code save value in `sales_Shipment_items` now as same i want to save value in `sales_shippment` table. 
which method i can make plugin or `event` ?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora is not edit my question  . it answer of my question read carefully

Comment: Okay @Hafiz-umer, I accept my mistake.